# When I have use ARC in IOS project,how can I use void *?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, void-pointers

LooK this method:
    beginAnimations:context: 
   This is a method of class UIView. The context need parameter which is a type of void-pointer,and I need to send a UIImageView to context.
   I get a warning,which says void* has been forbidden when I use ARC. So how can I send UIImageView to context except not use ARC.

Comment: Use UIView's block animation methods. It's more convenient because you don't neet an animation completion delegate somewhere else.

Comment: Plus the docs say to use the block animation methods.

Comment: Thanks for help.I will learn to use UIView's block animation methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above provided the correct answer for this particular case (use the block-based animation methods) but in general if you have an API which takes a context `void *` and you'd like to pass an object, I find it best to convert your `id` to a `CFTypeRef` so you can get manual memory management semantics on the pointer (`CFTypeRef` is a typedef for `void *`), etc. Note however that this requires that the callback **must** be called in order to get your object released (i.e. converted back to ARC's built-in management).

Here's an example for some imaginary API I just dreamt up:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithObject: (id) object {
    // use CFBridgingRetain() to turn object into a manually-retained CFTypeRef/void*
    [someObject performBackgroundTaskWithTarget: self
                                       selector: @selector(bgTask:)
                                        context: CFBridgingRetain(object)];
}

- (void) bgTask: (void *) context
{
    // use CFBridgingRelease() to turn our void*/CFTypeRef into an ARC-managed id
    id object = CFBridgingRelease((CFTypeRef)context);
    ...
}
```